# Can I transfer users from one Chrome web store hosted extension to another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have 2 almost identical extensions hosted on the Chrome web store. I want to merge these extensions, Or in other words transfer users from one extension to the other. Can I do that and how?

Comment: I've once created a module that's used to move users from one extension to another, see https://github.com/Rob--W/pdf.js/commit/67b286c540e94eeec52b1064bd839c33f2a6bfeb for the source code.

Comment: @RobW I did not understand from the code how the actual migration was done :( can elaborate a bit or just point me to the relevant lines of code?

Comment: All lines of code in that commit are relevant to the migration. What exactly do you not understand? I'd say that the variable and function names are quite descriptive.

Comment: @RobW besides showing a message telling the user to install the new extension, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No. The code for the migration assistent (see first comment) has to be embedded in the old extension. It suggests to download a new version of the extension, and once it detects that the new extension is installed, it uninstalls itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant. What you can do is take the one with the least users and make it show a message offering the users to install the other one.

Comment: Is this still current info in 2021?