# Change existing "extension ID" for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an existing extension in the chrome store, but I want to migrate users to another extension I developing with a different Extension ID, but still keep the existing one in the store.

Is there a way to do that? Maybe with Chrome extension API?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I transfer users from one Chrome web store hosted extension to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949601/can-i-transfer-users-from-one-chrome-web-store-hosted-extension-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. You have two possibilities as far as I can tell:

1. Publish your new extension, and make an update for the old extension asking the users to migrate with a link to web store. Not a great user experience though.
2. You could potentially replace your existing extension with your new one just as an update. That way you're forcing migration. You can then re-publish the old one under a new ID.

   Please note: this does look very shady and will probably trigger a manual review.